# Trying to unbind click event and attach new event

Tags: javascript, jquery, unbind

I am trying to unbind the click event and attach another click event after the button is clicked once.

```
<small id="selectall_agriculture" onclick="refineSearch.testing('agriculture')">(select all)</small>
```

After the testing function is run, I want the selectAllPropertyTypesInGroup() function to run, but instead, the testing function is called everytime.  If I take the onclick event out of the small tag and trigger the setGroupHeaderNotAllSelected() from another front end control, the click event that is created with $('#selectall_' + groupName).click() in the setGroupHeaderNotAllSelected() function works.  I feel like the unbind is not working because the click event is hard coded into the small tag.  Any suggestions?

```
refineSearch.testing = function (groupName) {
    console.log("Click event from front end running instead of the one binded");
    setGroupHeaderNotAllSelected (groupName);
};

var setGroupHeaderNotAllSelected = function (groupName) {
    $('#selectall_' + groupName).unbind('click');
    $('#selectall_' + groupName).click(function () {
        selectAllPropertyTypesInGroup(groupName);
        return false;
    });
};
```

Comment: change .click, for bind('click' ?

Comment: Remove the `onclick` attribute and attach the event using unobtrusive JS instead (eg. jQuery's `on()`), then use `off()` to remove the current event before you add the new one.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I do not believe that `off()` can "unbind" inline event handlers. However, you can set the `onclick` attribute to null which will effectively "unbind" it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I missed _onclick=_

Comment: @Satpal you made me doubt myself as I hadn't tried it in such a long time :)

Comment: @gforce301 I agree, although the setting to `null` is an ugly workaround for something which shouldn't be an issue when events are bound correctly.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Agreed, it is an ugly workaround but the OP did no specify if they had control over the original element definition. In case they don't, it is the only way I have ever been able to achieve the desired "unbinding".

Comment: I do not have control over the element.  Your comments are appreciated.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Per [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) the `unbind` method is deprecated, use `off` instead (`click` is fine, but you may [look at](http://api.jquery.com/on/) `on` method also)

```
$('#selectall_' + groupName).off('click').click(function () {
    selectAllPropertyTypesInGroup(groupName);
    return false;
});
```

Also, you need to choose between declarative `onclick` attribute set and jQuery binding. So instead on `onclick` attribute using, I would add the hanlder via script on the App start

```
$('#selectall_agriculture').click(function() { 
  refineSearch.testing('agriculture');
});
```